# Siamese Neural Network in TensorFlow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to implement a Siamese Neural Network in TensorFlow but I cannot really find any working example on the Internet (see [Yann LeCun paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/769-signature-verification-using-a-siamese-time-delay-neural-network.pdf)).

[image]

The architecture I'm trying to build would consist of two LSTMs sharing weights and only connected at the end of the network.

My question is: how to build two different neural networks sharing their weights (tied weights) in TensorFlow and how to connect them at the end?

Thanks :)

**Edit**: I implemented a simple and working example of a siamese network [here](https://github.com/benmyara/deeplearning-tensorflow/blob/master/notebooks/1_siamese.ipynb) on MNIST.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update with `tf.layers`

If you use the `tf.layers` module to build your network, you can simply use the argument `reuse=True` for the second part of the Siamese network:

```py
x = tf.ones((1, 3))
y1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 4, name='h1')
y2 = tf.layers.dense(x, 4, name='h1', reuse=True)

# y1 and y2 will evaluate to the same values
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(y1))
print(sess.run(y2))  # both prints will return the same values
```

---

### Old answer with `tf.get_variable`

You can try using the function `tf.get_variable()`. (See the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables))

Implement the first network using a variable scope with `reuse=False`:

```
with tf.variable_scope('Inference', reuse=False):
    weights_1 = tf.get_variable('weights', shape=[1, 1],
                              initializer=...)
    output_1 = weights_1 * input_1
```

Then implement the second with the same code except using `reuse=True`

```
with tf.variable_scope('Inference', reuse=True):
    weights_2 = tf.get_variable('weights')
    output_2 = weights_2 * input_2
```

The first implementation will create and initialize every variable of the LSTM, whereas the second implementation will use `tf.get_variable()` to get the same variables used in the first network. That way, variables will be **shared**.

Then you just have to use whatever loss you want (e.g. you can use the L2 distance between the two siamese networks), and the gradients will backpropagate through both networks, updating the shared variables with the **sum of the gradients**.

Comment: You can also define once all the variables, like `weights = tf.Variable(...)`, and then use these variables in each inference, `output_1 = weights * input_1` and `output_2 = weights * input_2`.  
As with shared variables, here the variable `weights` will receive two gradients and two gradient updates.

Comment: I've a doubt, is it necessary to use tf.get_variable()? Can we directly use tf.conv2d() without creating a variable using tf.get_variable() at all?

Comment: @kunal18 : I added an example with `tf.layers`

Comment: Thanks for the update! Can you please look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266886/defining-a-siamese-network-in-tensorflow